# HTML within XML without breaking validity

Tags: php, html, xml

I was hoping someone can help me with the following issue. As I am at a brick wall after a day  on this.

I am trying to take products descriptions from an online shops database and produce an XML feed.
The problem is the descriptions contain HTML so the XML breaks when viewing it in a browser

This is the line of code:-

```
echo    '<DESCRIPTION>' . $row['products_description'] . '</DESCRIPTION>';
```

I have tried the following:-

```
echo    '<DESCRIPTION><![CDATA[' . $row['products_description'] . ']]></DESCRIPTION>';
```

When i view the output it breaks the XML at the first

```
<BR>
```

I am aware of the htmlentities in PHP but this doesn't work as I pick up the XML from another shop to import the descriptions and they Wont display correctly when imported back in

I hope someone can help. Thanks for taking the time to look

Comment: could you provide the produced HTML?

Comment: Which DTD/Shema is your XML using?

Comment: The script produces a descriptions.xml

Comment: When you say using CDATA does not work, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Tidy the HTML first.

```
$config = array(
  'indent'         => true,
  'output-xhtml'   => true,
  'wrap'           => 200);

$tidy = new Tidy();
$tidy->parseString($row['products_description'], $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();

echo    '<DESCRIPTION>' . $tidy. '</DESCRIPTION>';
```

You will need to have the [libtidy extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.requirements.php) installed for this to work.

Comment: What didn't work?  Maybe entities need to be escaped as well.  Can you share the HTML?

Comment: Your code produces an error
     PHP Fatal error:  Class 'tidy' not found in xmlbuilder.php on line 393

Comment: I had a typo and edited the answer to fix it.  I also clarified that you need an extension enabled for tidy.